# Can I change data-open to data-close?

Tags: jquery, html, frameworks, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

Good day! I am new to Foundation 6 and I have a button that toggles into view my off-canvas.

```
<button class="hamburger-btn" type="button" data-open="mobile-nav">
```

And what I want to happen is that when someone clicks on it, and the off-canvas goes into view, the data-open turns into data-close, so it can hide the off-canvas when it is clicked again.

So it's something like below.

```
<button class="hamburger-btn" type="button" data-close>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Please use the `zurb-foundation` tags next time. The `foundation` tag is not related to ZURB Foundation and is for an Apple framework.

Comment: Thanks and sorry, this is my first time asking a question

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
$('.hamburger-btn').click(function() {
  if ($(this).attr('data-open')) {
    $(this).removeAttr('data-open');
    $(this).attr('data-close', "");
  } else {
    $(this).removeAttr('data-close');
    $(this).attr('data-open', "mobile-nav");
  }
})
```

**Demo**

```js
$('.hamburger-btn').click(function() {
  if ($(this).attr('data-open')) {
    $(this).removeAttr('data-open');
    $(this).attr('data-close', "");
  } else {
    $(this).removeAttr('data-close');
    $(this).attr('data-open', "mobile-nav");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="hamburger-btn" type="button" data-open="mobile-nav"></button>
```

Comment: In general there are also functions to do this using the `open` and `close` methods if this is what he needs: https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/off-canvas.html#open

Answer (score 0):

No need to switch between data-open and data-close, data-toggle to the rescue!

```
<button class="hamburger-btn" type="button" data-toggle="mobile-nav">
```

The above will open the nav if it's closed, and close it if it's open.